# gmake: How to assign global variable from shell command?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile that executes some shell command and I want to store the output to a global variable:

```
GLOBVAR = a

all:
    GLOBVAR=$(shell echo 'X')
    $(info $(GLOBVAR))
```

`GLOBVAR` is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up make and shell variables. In `GLOBVAR=$(shell echo 'X')` it is a shell variable that you assign, while in `$(info $(GLOBVAR))` it is a make variable that you expand.

Try this, instead:

```
GLOBVAR = $(shell echo 'X')

all:
    $(info $(GLOBVAR))
```

But there are several other issues with your Makefile that you should probably consider.

1. Using `$(shell...)` in recipes is not recommended because recipes are already shell scripts. So, if you want to assign a shell variable in a recipe, just:

   ```
    all:
        GLOBVAR="$$(echo 'X')"
   ```

   Note the `$$` to escape the expansion that make performs before passing the recipes to the shell.
2. The different lines of the recipe are executed in different shells. So, if you want to use in a line a shell variable that was assigned in a previous line you must join them:

   ```
    all:
        GLOBVAR="$$(echo 'X')"; echo $$GLOBVAR
   ```

   (same remark as before about `$$`). You can use line continuation if you prefer:

   ```
    all:
        GLOBVAR="$$(echo 'X')"; \
        echo $$GLOBVAR
   ```
3. And finally, if you want to assign make variables in recipes you can, with the `eval` make function, but I strongly discourage you to do so until you perfectly understand when make does what:

   ```
    $ cat Makefile
    .PHONY: all lla

    all:
        $(eval GLOBVAR = $(shell echo 'X'))
        @echo all: $(GLOBVAR)

    lla:
        @echo lla: $(GLOBVAR)
    $ make all
    all: X
    $ make lla
    lla:
    $ make all lla
    all: X
    lla: X
    $ make lla all
    lla:
    all: X
   ```

   And I let you imagine what the results could be with parallel make... In summary, if you start using make functions in recipes you are probably wandering into dangerous areas.